# get a specific value based on criteria from elasticsearch array using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My elastic search data looks like

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "eswar",
        "_type": "azure",
        "_id": "AV6y005oafdLlkt7Fe-R",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "costs": [
            {
              "cost": 3.6,
              "endDate": "2017-02-15T00:00:00+00:00",
              "startDate": "2017-02-14T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
              "cost": 2,
              "endDate": "2017-02-14T00:00:00+00:00",
              "startDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00+00:00"
            }
          ],
          "externalUUID": "/subscriptions/9ee6993f-a036-4118-9eab-c66d9fda1ef3/resourceGroups/VISTARAGATEWAYIMAGE/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/VistaraGateway01_disk1_ec7798e17f934e6483ed5d2490e80d98",
          "clientId": 154,
          "region": "useast",
          "cloudProviderId": 57063
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "eswar",
        "_type": "azure",
        "_id": "AV6y00rmafdLlkt7Fe-Q",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "costs": [
            {
              "cost": 0,
              "endDate": "2017-02-14T00:00:00+00:00",
              "startDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
              "cost": 3,
              "endDate": "2017-02-17T00:00:00+00:00",
              "startDate": "2017-02-16T00:00:00+00:00"
            }
          ],
          "externalUUID": "/subscriptions/9ee6993f-a036-4118-9eab-c66d9fda1ef3/resourceGroups/vistaragatewayimage/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VistaraGateway",
          "clientId": 154,
          "region": "eastus",
          "cloudProviderId": 57063
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get costs.cost:3.6 as aggregation result,but I am getting result as 5
how can I filter data even in array?

```
 RangeQueryBuilder startDateRQB = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("costs.startDate").gte("2017-02-14T00:00:00+00:00");
        RangeQueryBuilder endDateRQB = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("costs.endDate").lte("2017-02-15T00:00:00+00:00");
        RegexpQueryBuilder deviceNameREQB= QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("region", "useast.*");
        BoolQueryBuilder bQB=QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(deviceNameREQB).must(startDateRQB).must(endDateRQB);
        BoolQueryBuilder sQB=QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(startDateRQB).must(endDateRQB);
        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(bQB).addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("Totalcost").field("costs.cost")).execute().actionGet();
        Sum sum=response.getAggregations().get("Totalcost");
        double cost=sum.getValue();
        System.out.println(cost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to define `costs` as nested object.
Than, you will be able to add conditions on the data inside (nested documents).

This approach can open a wide range of possibilities to your queries.

Have a look at the following solution:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "costs_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "costs"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "bool_agg": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "costs.startDate": {
                  "gte": "2017-02-14T00:00:00+00:00"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "costs.endDate": {
                  "lte": "2017-02-15T00:00:00+00:00"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "costs.region": "useast.*"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "cost_sum_agg": {
            "sum": {
              "field": "costs.cost"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me explain every aggregation (by its name):

- costs_agg: nested aggregation to dive into costs scope
- bool_agg: the thing with aggregation over nested object its that, a query above the aggregation won't filter by nested objects. The solution here is to filter the needed nested-documents inside the aggregation itself
- cost_sum_agg: final sum

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Eli,thanks alot its very useful.can you provide the same solution in java.I am a bit confused how to write this solution in java.Thanks in advance